# Squash Commits Based On Author

Tags: git, version-control

In a repository there are a very large number of commits caused by automated build-tool updates to AssemblyInfo files (the project is in C#). These commits all have "Dev BuildAgent" as an author.

Is there any way to squash all commits in a repository from a specific author into the first child from another author?

Of course, one possibility would be to run `git rebase --interactive` using the SHA of the root commit and *manually* go through the list of commits and apply the squash command to the appropriate commit manually. However, it would be useful to know whether there is a quicker option, bearing in mind there are a very large number of commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To squash all commits of the author with email `foo@bar.com` into the next child commit of another author, you can use the following. You can of course also check any other attribute like author name, commiter email, committer name, ...

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "foo@bar.com" ] && skip_commit "$@" || git commit-tree "$@"'
```